# Help finding online Isekai fiction where the summoning targeted wrong time, and got a mangled body instead of a soul?

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai, reincarnation

Help me find online Isekai fiction where the summoning targeted wrong time, and got a mangled body instead of a soul.

All I know about its location is "likely on [Royal Road](https://www.royalroad.com)".

As for content, the protagonist got mangled in a traffic accident, not sure as a pedestrian or as a driver, but the state was related to me as "mangled".

They were supposed to be summoned into some revival procedure where they get blessings or some other boost, but the summoners messed up the timing somehow and got the mangled, still-living body, instead of the "hero" post-death as just a soul.

Due to the summoners not having prepared for such a summoning accident, the "hero" then died in the summoners' world, which sent its foreign soul into the reincarnation system of that world.

However, the soul carried the boosts still.

Comment: So does the story follow the mangled body, or the freed soul?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Ah, I think I fixed it? You were confused if the body was alive or dead when it was summoned right? The body was alive on summoning and died on arrival.

Comment: Ah! I get it now. So they meant to just summon his soul, which they could put into a body. Instead, they got the dying body, when then reincarnated outside of their control, with all of their buffs, and the narrative then follows that hero.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/j1ovo7/isekai_idea_dead_on_arrival/ :-D Unfortunately, no linked story.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I think that one's a story *idea*

Comment: @Valorum: Indeed, but I was amused that someone seemed to have written at least the prompt.